# XPath is Dynamic in the Application using Appium Inspector

Tags: appium, appium-ios

[i have attached the screen shot of the selected Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KvTL.png)
I am working on Mobile App Testing for iPhone, I am using Appium inspector to identify the elements, I have a scenario where bot replies a text while chatting with the Bot, so I need to identify the text first, for that I have only xpath, and that keeps changing, Apart from xpath I have attributes `type`, `enabled`, `visible`, `x`, `y`, `height`, `width`, can you please tell how to identify the text first using the attributes I mentioned?

```
public void verify_validatation_message() {
    MobileElement message = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"label_2\"])[62]/XCUIElementTypeOther");
    String validation_message = message.getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("I can see you've put a term of 45 years", validation_message);
}
```

[ScreenShot of Selected Element Continuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDMaD.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Please edit your question with relevant code.

Comment: public void verify_validatation_message() {
      MobileElement message = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"label_2\"])[62]/XCUIElementTypeOther");
     String validation_message = message.getText();
     Assert.assertEquals("I can see you've put a term of 45 years", validation_message);
     }

Comment: This is the code i have written, But the xpath is Dynamic and keeps changing, i have other attributes like type, enable,visible,x,y,height, width.

Comment: @saidayapule - Can you share screen shot of element inspection ?

Comment: @AmitJain i have added the screenshots